# Javascript value does not assign

Tags: javascript

i assigned place id here "placeid = results[0].place_id" but it dosen't. it returns me undefined. assignment operation fails there.

```
function match_up_dn(address)
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var placeid;

    if (geocoder) 
    {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               console.log("al:-"+results[0].place_id);
                placeid = results[0].place_id;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("undefined address");
            }
        });
    }

    return placeid;
}
```

Comment: Rewrite the question so it makes a little bit sense.

Comment: i assigned place id here "placeid = results[0].place_id" but it dosen't. it returns me undefined. assignment operation fails there.

Comment: I asked to rewrite, not copy paste the same one line you mentioned in the question. If you can't put up with trying to explain your problem, don't expect anyone to help you solve it.

Comment: print results in console and post the output here

Comment: console al:-ChIJsye0qmRO4DsR0O5B8KKafOA

Comment: problem is the outer function doesn't wait for inner function process complete. here the placeid returns before the inner function assign value to it. @jitendragarg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function match_up_dn(address)
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var placeid;

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               console.log("al:-"+results[0].place_id);
               placeid = results[0].place_id;
               return placeid;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("undefined address");
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: @MitulLakhani Try now this will definitely work.

Comment: Exactly you were not getting output because API call response functions run on background thread so main thread will return null before background thread update the value. Now as you move return statement to background thread it will solve your problem

Comment: it's works this way.

**match_dn(document.getElementById('recipient-address').value);**

Not this way

**else if(Origin_postal == match_dn(document.getElementById('recipient-address').value))**